# Issue while creating cartogram plot in r

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf, cartogram

I am new to `Spatial data` & `cartogram` lib and getting some issues while trying to recreate plot from: https://www.r-graph-gallery.com/a-smooth-transition-between-chloropleth-and-cartogram.html

[image]

**Lib & Data**

```
library(tidyverse)
library(maptools)
library(cartogram)
library(viridis)
library(sf)

data("wrld_simpl")

afr_cartogram = wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl$REGION==2,]
```

After this, I had some **error**: like `st_transform` ..... which I fixed it after some googling using `sf` lib.

```
afr_sf <- st_as_sf(afr_cartogram)

afr_sf_proj = st_transform(afr_sf,3857)

afr_plot <- cartogram::cartogram(afr_sf_proj, "POP2005", itermax =7)
```

**ISSUE:** Now after this step I am unable to recreate the code as it is in the **demo website** as I **do not have column `group` in my data**.

```
ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = afr_plot, aes(fill = POP2005/1000000, x = LON, y = LAT, group = group) , size=0, alpha=0.9) +
  theme_void()
```

From where can I get `group` column ???

**Code used in website:**

```
data(wrld_simpl)
afr=wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl$REGION==2,]

afr_cartogram <- cartogram(afr, "POP2005", itermax=7)

# Transform these 2 objects in dataframe, plotable with ggplot2
afr_cartogram_df <- tidy(afr_cartogram) %>% left_join(. , afr_cartogram@data, by=c("id"="ISO3")) 
afr_df <- tidy(afr) %>% left_join(. , afr@data, by=c("id"="ISO3")) 
 
# And using the advices of chart #331 we can custom it to get a better result:
ggplot() +
  geom_polygon(data = afr_df, aes(fill = POP2005/1000000, x = long, y = lat, group = group) , size=0, alpha=0.9) +
  theme_void() +
  scale_fill_viridis(name="Population (M)", breaks=c(1,50,100, 140), guide = guide_legend( keyheight = unit(3, units = "mm"), keywidth=unit(12, units = "mm"), label.position = "bottom", title.position = 'top', nrow=1)) +
  labs( title = "Africa", subtitle="Population per country in 2005" ) +
  ylim(-35,35) +
  theme(
    text = element_text(color = "#22211d"), 
    plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#f5f5f4", color = NA), 
    panel.background = element_rect(fill = "#f5f5f4", color = NA), 
    legend.background = element_rect(fill = "#f5f5f4", color = NA),
    plot.title = element_text(size= 22, hjust=0.5, color = "#4e4d47", margin = margin(b = -0.1, t = 0.4, l = 2, unit = "cm")),
    plot.subtitle = element_text(size= 13, hjust=0.5, color = "#4e4d47", margin = margin(b = -0.1, t = 0.4, l = 2, unit = "cm")),
    legend.position = c(0.2, 0.26)
  ) +
  coord_map()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `group` columns are produced in these lines

```r
afr_cartogram_df <- tidy(afr_cartogram) %>% 
   left_join(afr_cartogram@data, by = ("id" = "ISO3")) 
afr_df <- tidy(afr) %>% 
   left_join(afr@data, by = c("id" = "ISO3"))
```

by the `tidy` function from package `broom` which is not attached in your code!

Attach `broom` using `library(broom)` or call `tidy()` from its namespace like this: `broom::tidy(...)`.

The 'data section' in your code should look like this:

```r
data(wrld_simpl)
afr <- wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl$REGION==2, ]
afr_cartogram <- wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl$REGION == 2,]
afr_sf <- st_as_sf(afr_cartogram)
afr_sf_proj <- st_transform(afr_sf,  3857)
afr_plot <- cartogram_cont(afr_sf_proj, "POP2005", itermax =7)

afr_cartogram_df <- broom::tidy(afr_cartogram) %>% 
  left_join(afr_cartogram@data, by=c("id" = "ISO3")) 
afr_df <- broom::tidy(afr) %>% 
  left_join(afr@data, by=c("id" = "ISO3"))
```

The subsequent `ggplot` code works fine then:

[image]

Comment: Hi, since your answer gives a much better explanation, I deleted mine and added the code here. If you don't want it in, feel free to take it out.

Comment: Thanks @slamballais for helping me out on this. I Appreciate your help :)

Comment: Thanks @Martin C. Arnold for helping me out on this. I Appreciate your help :)

Comment: @slamballais thanks for the suggestion, I just added a few lines and the ggplot output (:

Comment: Hi @MartinC.Arnold i am little confused here as what are you referring `afr` as in **your code** which is used in line `afr_df <- tidy(afr) %>% `. As you have used `afr_cartogram <- wrld_simpl[wrld_simpl$REGION == 2,]` but I don't see the object `afr` creation anywhere in those lines but they are called in the code later.

Comment: You're right. I've added those lines to my answer.

Comment: Oh they both are same thing. I didn't know. Thanks for adding :)